# How to prevent overlapping TextViews - Android

Tags: java, android

I wanted to change textviews positions randomly when user touches one of them, and I managed it with this code:

```
    int leftDistance1 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);
    int leftDistance2 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);
    int leftDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);

    while(leftDistance1 == leftDistance2)
    {
        leftDistance2 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);
    }
    while(leftDistance1 == leftDistance3)
    {
        leftDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);
    }
    while(leftDistance2 == leftDistance3)
    {
        leftDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutWidth);
    }

    int topDistance1 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);
    int topDistance2 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);
    int topDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);

    while(topDistance1 == topDistance2)
    {
        topDistance2 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);
    }
    while(topDistance1 == topDistance3)
    {
        topDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);
    }
    while(topDistance2 == topDistance3)
    {
        topDistance3 = new Random().nextInt(layoutHeight);
    }

    params1.setMargins(leftDistance1, topDistance1, 0, 0);
    params2.setMargins(leftDistance2, topDistance2, 0, 0);
    params3.setMargins(leftDistance3, topDistance3, 0, 0);

    tv1.setLayoutParams(params1);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(params2);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(params3);
```

However, sometimes one textview may overlap other and blocks the user to touch the textview under it. As you can see from the code, I tried it with while loops but it didn't work. (Also, I tried it with if blocks, but it didn't work either.) How can I prevent this overlap?

Here is the XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tvw1" />

<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvw1"
    android:id="@+id/tvw2" />

<TextView android:text=""
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvw2"
    android:id="@+id/tvw3" />
```

Comment: we need to see your XML Layout..

Comment: OK I added my xml layout